# What is the order in a for loop?

Tags: c, math, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to solve Problem 5 of project euler and I the answer I keep getting is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    int num;
    int x = 0;
    for (num = 20; x == 0; num++)
    {
        if ((num%1) == 0 && (num%2) == 0 && (num%3) == 0 && (num%4) == 0 && (num%5) == 0 && (num%6) == 0 && (num%7) == 0 && (num%8) == 0 && (num%9) == 0 && (num%10) == 0 && (num%11) == 0 && (num%12) == 0 && (num%13) == 0 && (num%14) == 0 && (num%15) == 0 && (num%16) == 0 && (num%17) == 0 && (num%18) == 0 && (num%19) == 0 && (num%20) == 0)
        x = 1;
    }
    printf("%d %d", num, x);
}
```

My program keeps printing out `232792561` (I am aware that I'm printing x, this is simply for troubleshooting purposes).

The verbatim output I'm getting is: `232792561 1`.

I did some research and I found that the correct answer to the problem is `232792560`. 
I am now beginning to believe that the problem lies in the for loop.

What does the loop do first, the iteration (`num++`) or the test (`x == 0`)?

Comment: Don't make manual loops. Use the loop constructs of C.

Comment: Put a `break` after `x = 1`.

Comment: What is a break? Sorry I'm reading K&R 2nd edition, and I am just beginning to read the chapter on functions, and I'm afraid "breaks" have not yet been mentioned.

Comment: @David - You are allowed to turn to pages in the book beyond where you have read.  It would be good to read the section on ```for()``` loops instead of posting questions asking for something like that.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? My question does not break any rules? regardless of my poor programming skills, the question is a valid one, is it not?

Comment: @David - I downvoted this question because essentially you asked a question that can be answered from K&R book, or any book on C.  That's not the type of programming question I want to see here.

Comment: Should I delete it? Also wouldn't the question be good for archiving purposes (ie a beginner like me who wants to know the order of a for loop can just google instead of having to go to a book)?

Comment: @David You've been suggesting edits to questions. Please make sure that the edits are not minor (ie. moving tags in the question title)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the loop body has been executed (if at all, because first the initialisation code is run, then the condition checked to see whether the body is entered),

- first the update code is run
- then the condition is checked.

So after you set `x` to 1, `num` is incremented once more.

Instead of setting `x` to 1 to end the loop, you could simply `break;`, that would exit the loop without running the update code.

Answer (score 16):

A for loop can be converted to an equivalent while loop:

```
for (num = 20; x == 0; num++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

is the same as

```
num = 20;
while (x == 0) {
    // do stuff, then
    num++;
}
```

So first the condition is checked, then the loop body is executed, then the increment.

(And yes, as others suggested, if you `break;` out of the loop when you need, you'll need the correct result, since `break;` immediately jumps out of the loop, thus the incrementing statement isn't executed for the last time.)

Comment: `num` should begin from `20` in the second case.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes, thanks, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is needlessly complex and can be simplified using the `while` loop construct if you prefer. You can also get rid of the unnecessary variable `x`

```
int main() {
    int num = 20;
    while (!((num%1) == 0 && (num%2) == 0 && (num%3) == 0 && (num%4) == 0 && (num%5) == 0 && (num%6) == 0 && (num%7) == 0 && (num%8) == 0 && (num%9) == 0 && (num%10) == 0 && (num%11) == 0 && (num%12) == 0 && (num%13) == 0 && (num%14) == 0 && (num%15) == 0 && (num%16) == 0 && (num%17) == 0 && (num%18) == 0 && (num%19) == 0 && (num%20) == 0))
    {
        ++num;
    }
    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

To answer why your for loop was giving incorrect answer:

Although you were setting `x = 1` for the correct value of `num`, you were checking the condition of the `for loop` ONLY in the next iteration of the loop (i.e. after the `num++` statement is executed), and hence your value of `num` was offset by 1.

As many people suggested, you could use the `break` statement to terminate the for loop execution so that the value of `num` is what you want it to be when the control reaches outside the loop.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - yes I missed the return value, the OP's post did not even have a return type for the main function ;) Anyways updated

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - did you read the OP's post where he says what his expected answer is ?

Comment: correct  answer....:(

Comment: For **OP** please check the corrected Tuxdude's code working as you required. [codepad-link](http://codepad.org/PQZ33D7Z)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Initialization (`num = 20`)
Step 2: Test
Step 3: Iteration
Step 4: Test
Step 5: Iteration
and so on.

If I were you, I would choose `while` loop with condition as yours (I mean the long  one inside for loop) with body of incrementing.